# convert SLES11 SP1 vmlinuz-3.0.13-0.27-xen to VMware using vmware converter

Tags: xen, kernel, sles11

I am looking to convert a XEN VM (SLES11 SP1 kernel vmlinuz-3.0.13-0.27-xen) to a VMware guest using the VMware converter tool.

The VMware tool tell me conversion went fine. 100% OK, however, when I boot the VM on my VMware server, I get this error:

> root (hdo,0)
>   Filesystem type is ext2fs. partition typo 0x83
>   Kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.13-0.27-xen root=/dev/sda1 xencons=tty splash=silent
>   Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format
>   Press any key to continue...

Then it loop's...

Any one ? Lost here...
Not sure if I just give it another kernel.....

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is quite old, but here is what I did.

*Install the corresponding FULL Kernel. -> SET NEW FULL KERNEL TO DEFAULT ONE -> NO REBOOT !!! -> CONVERT TO VMWARE with VMWare Converter -> BOOT NEW VM.

And it work's !

P.S: To install corresponding FULL Kernel, I did use YAST (Since this is SLES), searched for the kernel in the package manager, and installed it. (The files where located in the OS .ISO DVD #1.